# Prorate days in months across multiple months

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have an example of a start date and end date below which is 1st Of December 2020 - 15th of February 2021

$startDate = '2020-12-01'
$endDate = '2021-02-15'

**Ideal result that i'm trying to achieve:**

December = 31 days 31 days = 1.0
January = 31 days / 31 days = 1.0
February = 15 days / 28 days = 0.53
Total Quantity = 2.53

**My current formula:**

$endDate->diffInDays($startDate)
77/90 days * 3 months = 2.57

```
$monthPeriod = CarbonPeriod::create($startDate, $endDate)->month();
$yearPeriod = CarbonPeriod::create($startDate, $endDate)->year();

$months = collect($monthPeriod)->map(function (Carbon $date) {
    return [
          'month' => $date->month,
           'name' => $date->format('F'),
           'days' => $date->daysInMonth,      
    ];
});

foreach ($months as $month) {
    $quantity = $endDate->diffInDays($startDate)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean December 2019?

Comment: my mistake, i've edited my end date

Answer (score 2):

```php
$startDate = Carbon::parse('2020-12-01');
$endDate = Carbon::parse('2021-02-15');
$startDate->floatDiffInMonths($endDate);
```

If the 15th is included, then you actually need to add 1 day so you get 16th midnignth as the end of the range:

```php
$startDate->floatDiffInMonths($endDate->addDay());
```

From the Carbon documentation:

```php
echo Carbon::parse('2000-01-15')->floatDiffInMonths('2000-02-24');               // 1.3103448275862
// floatDiffInMonths count as many full months as possible from the start date
// (for instance 31 days if the start is in January), then consider the number
// of days in the months for ending chunks to reach the end date.
```

Comment: Does this solve the issue of how to take into account the part about *February = 15 days / 28 days = 0.53*

Comment: You get 2.53 if you consider 16th midnight as the end of the range. Double check your formula, are you sure Feb 1st to 28th should give you 1 (and not 27/28)?

Comment: I'd recommend `$endDate->addDay()->subSecond()` to be more accurate, but yes @NigelRen it does give the OP's desired answer of 2.53571

Comment: In this case simply use `$endDate->endOfDay()` but it's actually not more accurate, as its' not a full day. Next day midnight is the correct thing to use if you want 1 to 31 Jan to be exactly 1 month. Subtract 1 second and 1 to 31 become 0.99999 I guess it's not what we can call accurate.